# <textarea> is inserting extra spaces if closing tag is on its own line

Tags: html, css, textarea

If I use this code:

```
<h5><strong>Back Order ETA: </strong></h5>
<textarea style="width: 100% " id="id_back_order_eta" class="editable form-control" rows="1">{{ ticket.back_order_eta }}
</textarea>
```

Whenever I click in the textarea on my page to start typing there are several extra blank spaces that I did not enter.

[image]

But if I use this code chunk instead:

```
<h5><strong>Back Order ETA: </strong></h5><textarea style="width: 100% " id="id_back_order_eta"
                                                    class="editable form-control"
                                                    rows="1">{{ ticket.back_order_eta }}</textarea>
```

It works properly with no extra spaces getting inserted.

[image]

I understand that the first snippet obviously is incorrect in some way because it is causing that extra space. But I can't figure out why, all of the tags are identical as far as I can tell. I don't see where the spaces could be coming from. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it's incorrect, but it's respecting the white space you're giving it at the outset.

That tag being on a new line doesn't exist in a vacuum.  There are white-space characters between the close of the opening tag and the open of the closing tag.

Remove that, and you're set.

## Example:

**Without whitespace:**

```
<textarea class="some-class">{{ my-textarea-value }}</textarea>
```

*Output*

> my textarea value

**With whitespace:**

```
<textarea class="some-class">
  {{ my-textarea-value }}
</textarea>
```

*Output*

> ```
>      my textarea value
> ```

## Another option:

You can use this trick that I sometimes advocate to remove white-space for `inline-block` elements to get rid of your extra spaces ***and*** preserve readability:

```
<textarea class="some-class"><!--
   -->{{my-textarea-value}}<!--
--></textarea>
```

The HTML comments will remove any extraneous white-space without requiring you to sacrifice the neatness of your markup.

Comment: Is it the newline causing the whitespace then? In my example `{{ my-textarea-value }}` is not indented like it is in yours.

Comment: In your case it's the trailing white-space.  So yes, it's the newline.  I'll add another option to the post to give you an additional route to take.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. My whitespace was before the closing tag. Neat trick with the comments. Thank you

Comment: Good answer, though I don't agree that a handful of comment tags should be considered "neat"

Comment: @JoshKG – You're entitled to your opinion.  It's provided as an option to folks who rely on indentation to read their code.